# What is a general word for one who creates an image, either by painting, drawing or other forms of illustrating?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage, synonyms

A writer is someone who writes anything: a comic book, an article, an essay, etc.

What would we call someone who creates an image by any means?

The word 'artist' is too broad, but the 'painter' is too narrow, while 'illustrator' doesn't quite capture it nicely. What is a better word?

Comment: Do you consider a *photographer* one who "creates an image by any means"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mention a *writer* but your question relates to imagery. I therefore take your question to refer to the illustrative part of things that are written.

I suggest that you have defined a niche of meaning between *artist* and *illustrator* so narrow that there is nothing to fill it. Consider a couple of relevant dictionary definitions for each word:

> *illustrator* =
>
> a person who draws pictures, especially for books
>
> [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/illustrator)
>
> A person who draws or creates pictures for magazines, books, advertising, etc
>
> [lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/illustrator)

> *artist* =
>
> someone who paints, draws, or makes sculptures
>
> [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/artist)
>
> one who professes and practices an imaginative art
>
> [Merriam webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/artist)

If we forget the sculptural aspect (which can hardly be relevant to written works ) and look for the extra connotations of *artist* that are not present in *illustrator* we are left with a very small area of meaning associated with imagination (or perhaps creativity?). But an illustrator of books, whether a novel, a comic, a graphic novel or other genres, is necessarily imaginative (and creative). Consequently I can find no word in my vocabulary to answer your need; I suggest *illustrator* remains the best word to use.

Comment: Also 'artist' is a very wide term with many sub-divisions, not all of them to do with the visual arts (you get people described as "performance artists") for example. You do sometimes see "photographic artist" but that is rare. The most general one for people working on publications would be "graphic artist" though whether that would cover all illustrators is open to interpretation.

Comment: Artist should do, then. Thanks!

Comment: Agreed. Artist and illustrator both seem to fit your criterion. I tried hard to think of another but my brain's "word bag" is empty in that area!